# Query from template to controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this code:

```
@foreach($data as $Branch)
     <tr class="item{{$Branch->id}}">
        <td> <a class="name">{{$Branch->branchs_name}}</a> </td>
        <td> <a class="name">{{$Branch->cashier_id}}</a> </td> 
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Can you help me how can I send this  `$Branch->cashier_id` back into the controller to query the Full Name of the cashier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead use `relationship`. Make a `belongsTo` relationship in your `Branch` Model like

```
public function cashier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cashier','cashier_id','id');
}
```

And in your view-

```
@foreach($data as $Branch)
          <tr class="item{{$Branch->id}}">
            <td> <a class="name">{{$Branch->branchs_name}}</a> </td>
            <td> <a class="name">{{$Branch->cashier->name}}</a> </td> 
           </tr>

@endforeach
```